# FrontDoor Bicep Fails - How do I get the reason?

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-front-door

I have a bicep that adds a front door endpoint and origin. It is failing with:

> The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because
> it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.

That's the raw error I see in the Resource Group Deployment in the UI.

This bicep takes parameters and it works for another app service. These parameters are identical, except for the app service and end point name.

I am deploying the bicep with this command:

> New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName
> $FrontDoorResourceGroupName -Mode Incremental -TemplateFile
> .\bicep\frontdoor.bicep -TemplateParameterObject
> $templateParameters -DeploymentDebugLogLevel All

I tried to validate the deployment with Test-AzDeployment, but it gives no meaningful information.

Here is the vague entry from the resources deployment, in the Azure UI.
[image]

How can I get more information about why it failed?

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried so far? @Don Chambers

Comment: I added the command I am using.

Answer (score 0):

> Front Door Bicep Fails - How do I get the reason?

After a workaround on your requirement, I found below ways to retrieve the error information more explicitly in bicep.

*Approach-1:*

The `PowerShell` command  `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` has an argument named

[`-DeploymentDebugLogLevel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-10.4.1#-deploymentdebugloglevel) provides detailed error information including line and column numbers. `DeploymentDebuglevel` can be enabled as per your requirement. This option is incompatible with CLI deployment.

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "xxxx" -TemplateFile "/home/xx/new.bicep" -DeploymentDebugLogLevel All
```

[image]

*Approach-2:*

You can use the Bicep `build` command to acquire troubleshooting information. The output includes the line and column number of each error, as well as the error message.

Build the bicep file by passing an argument [`--Debug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/bicep?view=azure-cli-latest#az-bicep-build-optional-parameters) along with the `az bicep build` command. It will also retrieve the information with the line numbers and a clear error message.

Refer [Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/find-error-code.md) Doc for more related information.

*Approach-3:*

And also [`Test-AzDeployment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/test-azdeployment?view=azps-10.4.1) helps you to validate the deployment and shows the error messages if any. This might not be an efficient way if you have multiple blockers.

*Approach-4:*

The last one would be checking portal deployment history. It might not be helpful in few scenarios. To check this, go to your deployment `resource group` and then choose `deployments` under `settings`. You will be able to view the below deployments history page as shown.

[image]

You can also refer [Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/import-export/storage-import-export-tool-reviewing-job-status-v1.md) MS Doc for more related information on your issue.

Comment: I already had -DeploymentDebugLogLevel All in my command. It just gives the generic messgage.
I will update the original post with the command I use.

Comment: As mention in the original post, I tried number 4. It only give me the generic message.

Comment: Have you tried all the ways I have given above? @DonChambers

Comment: Yes.Most before i posted except for test-azdeployment.  I eventually figured out the problem by trial and error.  I never found a way to get information.

Comment: Have you tried `az bicep build --debug` command too? @DonChambers